# Send html email with multiple embedded images using python script

Tags: python

I am newbie to Python. I wanted to send html based email with multiple embedded images

With the following code the email is absolutely working but able to view only one embedded image and another one as undefined

```
def addMultipleEmbeddedImages(self, nbMsg=1):

        attachedFiles = ["giga_logo_300x225.png", "phone_logo.jpg"]

        self.imgHtml = ""

        for file1 in attachedFiles:
            file = os.path.join(pathToAttachments, file1)                       

            self.__msg = MIMEMultipart('related')

            self.imgHtml +='<p <u>Embedded Images</u></p><br><img src="cid:%s"><br>'%file     

            self.__msg.attach(MIMEText(self.imgHtml, 'html'))

            fp = open(file, 'rb')
            msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
            fp.close()

            msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<%s>'%file)
            self.__msg.attach(msgImage)            

        self.__fillInAddressFields()

        # Attach the email in the body
        self.__buildBody(self.__msg)

        # Send the email with the embedded image
        self.__sendMessages(nbMsg)

        return
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing angle bracket on your first <p> element.

Comment: and.. you probably want to generate the first part of your html outside the loop so you don't have the phrase "Embedded Images" appearing above each image.

Answer (score 0):

```
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read(),name = os.path.basename(file1))
```

here i set the name for every image.