# Embedded html images not showing when send email with pyhton

Tags: python, html, image, email, mime-mail

I am trying to send HTML templates with python via Gmail but some images not sending. If send image separately it works. But maybe something in the HTML code makes the problem.

This is my piece of code where I send the email:

```
try:
      with SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        username, password = cred[0], cred[1]
        self.message_label.setText('Checking credentials...')
        sleep(1)
        try:
          smtp.login(username, password)
          succeed = 0
          for i in range(1):##cahnge linelen(data_contacts[0])
            test = True
            receiver = data_contacts[0][i]
            sleep(1)
            msg_root = MIMEMultipart('related')

            msg_root['From'] = username
            msg_root['To'] = receiver
            msg_root['Subject'] = data_contacts[1][i]

            msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg_root.attach(msg_alternative)

            try:
              with open(f'{data_contacts[2][i]}.html', 'r') as file:
                contents = file.readlines()
              contents = ''.join(contents)
          
              pattern = r'src="(.*?)"'
              match = set(findall(pattern, contents))
              print(match)
              print(pattern)
              ids = {}
              for index, path in enumerate(match):
                  ids[path] = f"image_{index}"

              for path in match:
                contents = sub(rf"{path}", rf"cid:{ids[path]}", contents)
              with open('test_html.html', 'w') as f:
                f.write(contents)

              msg_text = MIMEText(contents, 'html', 'utf-8')
              msg_alternative.attach(msg_text)

              self.message_label.setText(f'Sending {i+1}/{len(data_contacts[0])}')
              sleep(1)
              try:
                list_images = listdir(f'{data_contacts[2][i]}')
                for image in list_images:
                  with open(f'{data_contacts[2][i]}/{image}', 'rb') as file:
                    msgImage = MIMEImage(file.read(), name = basename(image))
                    path = f'{data_contacts[2][i]}/{image}'
                    try:
                      msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', f'<{ids[path]}>')
                      msg_root.attach(msgImage)
                    except:
                      get_exception()
                      test = False
                smtp.sendmail(username, receiver, msg_root.as_string())
                self.message_label.setText('Sent')
                succeed += 1
                sleep(1)
                self.notifyProgress.emit(int((i+1)*100/(len(data_contacts[0]))))
              except Exception as e:
                self.message_label.setText(f'{data_contacts[2][i]} folder must exists')
                sleep(1)
                self.message_label.setText('')
                test = False
            except Exception as e:
              self.message_label.setText(f'{e} {data_contacts[2][i]}.html not found')
              print((f'{e} {data_contacts[2][i]}.html not found'))
              sleep(1)
              self.message_label.setText('')
              test = False
            if i != len(data_contacts[0])-1 and test:
              self.message_label.setText(f'Waiting {delay} seconds')
              sleep(delay)
            else:
              self.notifyProgress.emit(int((i+1)*100/(len(data_contacts[0]))))
              sleep(1)
          self.notifyProgress.emit(100)
          sleep(1)
          self.message_label.setText('')
          sleep(1)
          self.notifyProgress.emit(0)
        except:
          self.message_label.setText(f"Can't login in {username}")
          get_exception()
    except:
      self.message_label.setText("Can't connect to server")
```

HTML template: https://github.com/mihai-python/html

Tried to send pieces of HTML and it works, but the whole HTML is a problem.

Also tried all these answers:

[Send html email with multiple embedded images using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221006/send-html-email-with-multiple-embedded-images-using-python-script)

[send html email with embedded image using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186048/send-html-email-with-embedded-image-using-python-script)

Nothing working